# Can I change a strokeEnd property without animation?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I can't seem to remove the animation from the `strokeEnd` property of my CAShapeLayer.

The documentation says the property is `animatable` but not that is animated by default and I can't pinpoint the problem. Any suggestions where to look?

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let circle = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Circle
        circle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        circle.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        circle.lineWidth = 10
        circle.strokeEnd = 0
        circle.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        circle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(60, 140, 200, 200)).CGPath
        circle.actions = ["strokeEnd" : NSNull()]

        // Show Button
        let showButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 40))
        showButton.addTarget(self, action: "showButton", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        showButton.setTitle("Show circle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        showButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        // Add to view
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(circle, atIndex: 1)
        self.view.addSubview(showButton)
    }

    func showButton() {
        circle.strokeEnd = 1
    }
}
```

[image: CAShapeLayer strokeEnd animation]

Comment: What's the point of `circle.actions = ["strokeEnd" : NSNull()]`?

Comment: Apparently the CAShapeLayer has default actions (animations) for it's properties..

Comment: - Removed solution from question and added it to the answer below..

Comment: I don't get it. If that solved your problem, hadn't you tested the above code before?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The approach you describe of setting the layer's strokeEnd action to NSNull works but it's a bit of a sledgehammer. When you do that you kill implicit animation of the strokeEnd property of your layer forever.

If that's what you want, that's ok. However, I tend to prefer using the second approach that David Rönnqvist lists in [**the answer you linked**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688363/change-cashapelayer-without-animation):
Making your layer change inside a CATransaction begin/commit block. Here is the code for that from David's answer (which is excellent, as his posts always are).

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
// change your property here 
yourShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.7;
[CATransaction commit]; // animations are disabled until here...
```

That code is in Objective-C. Translating it to Swift isn't too bad:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
yourShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.7
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: @Tieme, you should accept either your answer or mine, so other readers know you found a solution.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit busy yesterday.

Comment: You just saved me from a huge refactor. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I've found the problem. This solves it:

```
circle.actions = ["strokeEnd" : NSNull()]
```

More info can be found here: [Change CAShapeLayer without Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688363/change-cashapelayer-without-animation)

Comment: The approach you describe of setting the layer's strokeEnd action to NSNull works but it's a bit of a sledgehammer.  It permanently removes changes to the strokeEnd property from this and all future animations. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough. I found your answer recently and wanted to document the pros and cons of the different approaches for other readers though.